# Extract disjoint columns from Matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider a matrix

```
(mat = Array[a, {5, 5}]) // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

If I want to extract columns `2` through `4` which would return a `5x3` matrix, I can do that with:

```
mat[[;; , 2 ;; 4]] // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

But what if I want to extract only column `2` and `4` (without column `3`), so that I get a `5x2` matrix? Is there a short syntax to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18463/121

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rows 2 and 4 can be extracted with `mat[[{2, 4}]]`.

Columns 2 and 4 can be extracted with `mat[[All, {2, 4}]]` or equivalently `mat[[;;, {2, 4}]]`, or even `Part[mat, All, {2, 4}]`.